# nginx as dynamic reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx

I'd like to configure nginx in such a way that:

A request for `http://nginx-proxy-server.com/location1/filename.bin`
is proxied to `http://location1.my-application-server.com/filename.bin`

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/(.+)/(.*)$ {
    resolver 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass http://$1.my-application-server.com/$2$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't realize you could reference regex matches like that

Comment: This is not quite correct, I also need a "resolver" directive. Took me a long time to figure that one out.